# Unexpected assembly output when passing a structure by value

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm currently researching the passing of structs by value.
I have following code:

```
typedef struct s2{
    double d1;
    double d2;
    int a;
}S2;

void f_(S2 s);//Some external function, only used for compiling, so I can see the passing of parameters.

void f(){
    S2 s=(S2){0.5,1.0,1};
    f_(s);
}
```

If I compile it with `-Og -S -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables`, I get following assembly output:

```
f:
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
    movq    .LC1(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, 16(%rsp)
    movl    $1, 24(%rsp)
    pushq   24(%rsp)
    pushq   24(%rsp)
    pushq   24(%rsp)
    call    f_@PLT
    addq    $72, %rsp
    ret
    .size   f, .-f
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align 8
.LC0:
    .long   0
    .long   1071644672
    .align 8
.LC1:
    .long   0
    .long   1072693248
```

This assembly code, namely the passing over the stack was quite unexpected.
Look into the [System V Application Binary Interface](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf). At page 17 following, the parameter passing is outlined.

The classification of the parameters is described on page 18-19.

> The classification of aggregate (structures and arrays) and union types works as follows:

1. If the size of an object is larger than four eightbytes, or it contains unaligned fields, it has class MEMORY. (`S2` has the size `2*sizeof(double)+sizeof(int)=24`, so less than 32 bytes.)

...Skipping 2, as it refers to C++....

3. If the size of the aggregate exceeds a single eightbyte,  each is classified separately. Each eightbyte gets initialized to class NO_CLASS. (This is true. So we have to classify each one)

Some definitions:

> Arguments of types (signed and unsigned) _Bool,char,short,int,long,long long, and pointers are in the INTEGER class.

> Arguments of types float,double,_Decimal32,_Decimal64 and __m64 are in class SSE.

Each member classified:

```
typedef struct s2{
    double d1;//SSE
    double d2;//SSE
    int a;//INTEGER
}S2;
```

Then how each argument should be passed:

> 2. If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence %rdi,%rsi,%rdx,%rcx,%r8 and %r9 is used

> 3. If the class is SSE, the next available vector register is used, the registers are taken in the order from %xmm0 to %xmm7.

So my proposal for the register allocation looks like this:

```
xmm0: d1
xmm1: d2
rsi:  a
```

This is clearly wrong, as shown by the compiler that passes the argument using the stack.

Where is my error? What detail did I miss?

Comment: `sizeof(S2)` definitely *isn't* `20`, because `sizeof(S2)%sizeof(double)` *must be* `0`.

Comment: Okay. But this shouldn't change the outcome, whether it are 20 or 24 bytes, as the "magic value" to make an aggregate MEMORY is 32 bytes. (Or 4 eightbytes)

Comment: Definitelly too large https://godbolt.org/z/3TWs4d

Comment: @P__J__ I think you missed the `int a` in the struct definition

Comment: @JCWasmx86  - when I made it smaller - it is passing in registers. It was intentionally and I believe my comment explains it

Comment: later in the document: *5. Then a post merger cleanup is done: [...] (c) If the size of the aggregate exceeds two eightbytes and the first eight-
byte isn’t SSE or any other eightbyte isn’t SSEUP, the whole argument
is passed in memory.*

Comment: Ah, now I understand it. I read the fifth step, but somehow didn't quite understand it. Both your explanations together make now sense. Thanks.

Comment: Please consider making it an answer then for future users. :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I will wait until tomorrow and then I will make an answer, except somebody else wrote one